# OpenLayers/Geoserver rendering transformation is failing at the Prime Meridian

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

I have a layer that represents surface pressure in GeoServer. I am using a rendering transformation SLD to generate the contours. When I try to map it in OpenLayers, the contours show up fine when zoomed out all of the way.

However, when you zoom in, the contours disappear at the Prime Meridian. I'm thinking there may be an issue with how GeoServer or the SLD are handling this area and am wondering if anyone knows of a solution.

I'm not totally sure if this is an issue within OpenLayers or if it is an issue with my SLD in GeoServer. I'm thinking it is in GeoServer specifically with the rendering transformation because layers that do not have a rendering transformation show up fine.

Please see a screenshot of the issue below.

[image: works fine]

[image: contour layer cutoff at prime meridian]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9036), you can attempt to fix it and [submit a pull request](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/policies/pull_request.html), [sponsor a fix](http://geoserver.org/support/) or wait for a developer to get to it in their spare time.